# Nginx connection refused while resolving

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have simple application that has public address, lets say `http://example.com`
I need to setup reverse proxy which will forward requests to this service, so I running `nginx` as `docker` image, with following configuration.

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header "Connection" "";

            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_pass http://example.com;
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working, I'm receiving bunch of

> send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver:
> 127.0.0.11:53

And finally,

> example.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out),

Comment: Is example.com set to be your localhost?

Comment: Where does the `resolver` IP address come from; does deleting that line help at all?

Comment: It is not localhost. Removing it causes `no resolver defined to resolve example.com`. It comes from another stackoverflow answer, which says that it is IP of dns resolver of docker container

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use Google Public DNS. On top of that I had to turn of `ipv6` as it was causing other issues.

`resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;`